# WebRTC library remote audio rendering via AddSink

Tags: webrtc, libjingle

When the connection is set up and ready my `webrtc::PeerConnectionObserver` implementation receives a call to

```
void OnAddStream(webrtc::MediaStreamInterface* stream);
```

where I pull the `webrtc::AudioTrackInterface` out of the `webrtc::MediaStreamInterface`.

I get a valid (non-null) pointer back from this, call it `track`

```
webrtc::AudioTrackInterface* track;
```

and I proceed to call `track->AddSink(sink)`, where `sink` is my instance of a class that inherits from `webrtc::AudioTrackSinkInterface` and implements

```
  virtual void OnData(const void* audio_data,
                      int bits_per_sample,
                      int sample_rate,
                      int number_of_channels,
                      int number_of_frames) = 0;
```

At this point I expect to recieve regular callbacks into my concrete class with the decoded audio data, just like I receive calls into my `webrtc::VideoRendererInterface` with a `cricket::VideoFrame*` when video data is available, but I do not.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, except for using an interface that isn't implemented yet. Well, the *interface* is implemented, but there's no code behind it to actually call your `OnData()` method!

The interface in question is in WebRTC's [**mediastreaminterface.h**](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/talk/app/webrtc/mediastreaminterface.h). There's a note farther down in the file that hints at the unimplemented status of `AddSink()` and `OnData()`:

```
// Get a pointer to the audio renderer of this AudioTrack.
// The pointer is valid for the lifetime of this AudioTrack.
// TODO(xians): Remove the following interface after Chrome switches to
// AddSink() and RemoveSink() interfaces.
virtual cricket::AudioRenderer* GetRenderer() { return NULL; }
```

Unfortunately, the `AudioRenderer` class referenced here doesn't look very easy to work with. It's defined in Chromium's [**audio_renderer.h**](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/master/media/base/audio_renderer.h) and uses all sorts of Chromium internal types. If you figure out what to do with it, please let me know, because I am trying to solve the same problem myself.

I did notice some code in WebRTC's [**mediastreamhandler.cc**](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/talk/app/webrtc/mediastreamhandler.cc) that uses `OnData()` in the same way you and I are trying to do. There is a `LocalAudioTrackHandler` constructor that calls `track->AddSink()` on the audio track and passes it an instance of the `LocalAudioSinkAdapter` class. This class has an `OnData()` method which forwards to `sink_->OnData()`. The `track->AddSink()` call does get executed, but the `OnData()` method never gets called!

I think this `AddSink()`/`OnData()` code was added in anticipation of Chromium implementing these calls internally, so when they do switch over it will start using this code instead of the `AudioRenderer` code. That avoids the need to update both codebases in perfect sync with each other.

So all I can suggest is to wait until the code to call `OnData()` is implemented inside Chromium.

Comment: So, did this ever get implemented? The comments in mediastreaminterface.h don't seem to be there any more, but I'm trying to use AudioTrackSinkInterface and the onData callback never gets called.

Comment: Looks like it is implemented, but (as far as I can tell) it only works for the remote stream, not the local one (VideoSinkInterface works for both)